# Is it possible to create additional folders in the Views and ViewModels folders in Avalonia or is this a bad ton?

Tags: c#, .net, avaloniaui, avalonia

I'm doing a project and this question came up, as there will be a lot of files and it will be inconvenient to keep them in two folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not considered to be a bad tone. The one thing I would consider is to group your views by their functions or any similar logic.

Hope it helps